# SQL count changes by group (repetitive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, lag

With SQL, I'm trying to count the changes in assigned group on a ticket- once by the certain group, once by a SUbgroup, once by one group to another.

Current data:

| Number | Group | Subgroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A.1 |
| 1 | A | A.2 |
| 1 | B | B.1 |
| 1 | C | C.1 |
| 1 | C | C.2 |
| 1 | A | A.1 |
| 2 | A | A.1 |
| 2 | B | B.1 |
| 2 | C | C.1 |
| 2 | A | A.2 |
| 2 | B | B.2 |

Needed result 1, Number "1": Count changes by Group- 3 (A to B, B to C, C to A); Number 2 - 3
Needed result 3: Number 1: Count changes by subgroup- 5
Needed result 2: Count changes only from group A to group B - 1; Number 2= 2

How would I write this?

Tried to use this suggested query for the first result, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
WITH  Groups_Lag AS
(
    SELECT [Number], [Group], LAG([Group], 1) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS lag_kpi
from [test].[dbo].[test2]
)
,
final as (
SELECT [Number], [Group],lag_kpi, (Case when [Group] = lag_kpi then 0 else 1 end) as check_col
FROM Groups_Lag
GROUP by [Number], [Group], lag_kpi)
 
select sum(check_col) -1
from final
```

Comment: Nothing in your data appears to define the order. YOu need something to define that before you can achieve your expected results. Why, for example, is `A` before `C` and `C` is before `A`? (Yes, it's intentional that that question contradicts itself)

Comment: I have also a Submit_date column, so the tasks are ordered by it

Comment: There is no such column in your sample data though, so for us (other users on [so]), it doesn't exist.